# How to connect to a newly bought wifi router (to which I have never connected before) via command prompt in windows 8?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, command-line, router

I am new to command prompt and I am learning it for about some weeks,   I wanted to test myself by connecting to a newly bought wifi router, but in doing so I am facing some problems.

As far as I know to connect to a wifi network the command used is

```
netsh wlan connect name='profile' ssid='ssid' interface='interface'
```

But the problem i face is regarding the name(Profile). when I type the command

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

The cmd shows me the profiles of the networks I have connected to before, but we require the name(profile) part to connect to a wifi network, so how can I connect to a network I have never connected before?

When I type the command

```
netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid
```

I can see a list of available networks and their BSSIDs also I can see my
network's name there, but how do I connect to it? Also is there any way to connect to a network using the bssid or ssid of it. Please help me.

Screenshots of my progress so far.

[image: Two pics one showing the available profiles while the other shows a failed attempt to connect with ssid] (The second pic above shows a failed attempt to connect with the ssid)

[image: The bssids of the available networks] (The one encircled is our concern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I connect to a wireless network I have never connected before?

Export an existing profile, modify xml as appropriate, import modified profile:

> First you export an existing wifi profile:
>
> ```
> netsh wlan export profile name="WifiNetwork" folder="C:\path\" key=clear
> ```
>
> Then you get a XML file with the following style:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
> <name>WifiNetwork</name>
> <SSIDConfig>
>     <SSID>
>         <hex>123456789ABCDEF</hex>
>         <name>WifiNetwork</name>
>     </SSID>
> </SSIDConfig>
> <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
> <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
> <MSM>
>     <security>
>         <authEncryption>
>             <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
>             <encryption>AES</encryption>
>             <useOneX>false</useOneX>
>         </authEncryption>
>         <sharedKey>
>             <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
>             <protected>false</protected>
>             <keyMaterial>Password123</keyMaterial>
>         </sharedKey>
>     </security>
> </MSM>
> ```
>
> Than you can modify this file and import it to add this wifi with this
>   command:
>
> ```
> netsh wlan add profile filename="C:\path\WifiNetwork.xml"
> ```

Source [Add wlan profile with password in windows programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232162/add-wlan-profile-with-password-in-windows-programmatically), answer by [cSteusloff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3666741/csteusloff)